# Unity console error with only a timestamp

Tags: unity, console

I am getting console errors that only have a timestamp. I am running Unity 2019.1.9f1 on Ubuntu 19.04. I have installed dotnet core 2.2.5 on my machine.

[image]

Here is the full error log: https://pastebin.com/7vfAK9fZ

Here is a particularly suspect part of the log:

```
-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: 134--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/Unity.TextMeshPro.dll
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
No usable version of the libssl was found
/home/username/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.9f1/Editor/Data/Tools/RoslynScripts/unity_csc.sh: line 64:  3902 Aborted                 
"/home/username/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.1.9f1/Editor/Data/Tools/RoslynScripts/../../Tools/Roslyn/csc" /shared /noconfig @Temp/UnityTempFile-2773a2345220fccdfb0171165a73fa25
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
- Finished compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.TextMeshPro.dll
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: did you at any point use Unity's error logging. Do a text for any of the logging functions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Ubuntu 19.04 is not supported https://forum.unity.com/threads/empty-log-errors-in-2019-1-0f2.669961/

Comment: Dangerously close to a link-only answer, but +1 anyway since the link does include a potential workaround which seems to match the LibSSL errors in OP's log

Comment: Can you include this workaround in the body of the answer, in case the link rots?

Answer (score 0):

Check the editor log:

- Click the console's window dropdown icon
- Select `Open Editor Log`

[image]

Comment: It's too big to put in the body so I included a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/7vfAK9fZ